# How to get the _locale variable inside in a Symfony layout?

Tags: templates, layout, routes, translation, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 2 on a site which having 2 languages,
and I want to change patterns of my routes depending on user locale language !

Example:

```
user_login_en:
    pattern:  /en/user/login.html
    defaults: { _controller: SfErrorsAppBundle:User:login, _locale: en }

user_login_fr:
    pattern:  /fr/utilisateur/connexion.html
    defaults: { _controller: SfErrorsAppBundle:User:login, _locale: fr}
```

Inside a template, this is not difficult, i just have to pass the $this->get('session')->getLocale() from the controller to the template...

To work, I have to call my routes:

```
$router->generate('user_login_'.$locale, array());
```

But  inside my layouts, I have of course a menu, and sidebars, which have links... So I want to get the locale variable to use it ! So my question is simple: how to get this variable inside a "layout" template ? Otherwise, have you got any idea to change the pattern depending on the language ?

The reasons are that I want beautiful routes for all users, whether they're english or french... And also for a SEO reason !

Answer (score 184, accepted):

---**UPDATED FROM THE COMMENTS**---

As Symfony 2.1, you must use

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

or

```
{{ app.request.getLocale() }}
```

which returns `app.request.locale` if available and `app.request.defaultLocale` if `app.request.locale` is not set.

Comment: As Symfony 2.1, you must use `app.request.locale` instead.

Comment: @Damien and in a php template?

Comment: @DomingoSL `$view['request']->getLocale()`

Comment: Also in twig i would prefer `{{ app.request.getLocale() }}` since it returns `app.request.locale` if available and `app.request.defaultLocale` if `app.request.locale` is not set.

Comment: Updated the answer with the comments of [Damien](http://stackoverflow.com/users/665923/damien) and [Anticom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/966530/anticom)

Comment: Actually, these two options both do the same thing.  In Twig, the dot syntax can be used to access getter methods if there's no public property with the name provided (as here - the `locale` property on requests is protected).  For the exact rules of how the dot operator works in Twig, see the "Implementation" section under http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

Answer (score 106):

As Symfony 2.1 stores the "locale" in the Request instead of the session you have to use this:

```
{{ app.request.getLocale() }}
```

instead of app.session.locale

Comment: this one should be accepted, as the other one is outdated and therefore misleading

Comment: I guess I had the same experience as those people, who just lost 5 minutes with the first accepted answer, @Sybio please change accepted answer

Comment: Maybe should have made the effort to *update* the accepted answer with this ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Also, you might want to simplify your routing (one single rule):

```
user_login:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/user/login.html
    defaults: { _controller: SfErrorsAppBundle:User:login }
```

If you want to allow only some languages you can add a requirement:

```
user_login:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/user/login.html
    defaults: { _controller: SfErrorsAppBundle:User:login }
    requirements:
       _locale: fr|en
```

Comment: in order to add a requirement you have to use the "requirements" keyword. you missed the final "s" => http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is the **most easy and maintenable way** to autodetect the locale without worrying for *Symfony* version:

```
{% if not app.session.locale is null %} {# Prior to Symfony 2.1 you must get from session, it will be null if upper #}
    Locale: {{ app.session.locale }}
{% else %} {# With Symfony 2.1 or upper you only can get the locale from request #}
    Locale: {{ app.request.locale }}
{% endif %}
```

Also, if you prefer it you can use a *object like notation* in [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) template engine:

```
{% if not app.getSession().getLocale() is null %} {# Prior to Symfony 2.1 you must get from session, it will be null if upper #}
    Locale: {{ app.getSession().getLocale() }}
{% else %} {# With Symfony 2.1 or upper you only can get the locale from request #}
    Locale: {{ app.getRequest().getLocale() }}
{% endif %}
```

See [Symfony 2.1.0 release notes](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-1-0-released) for more info